# Regular expression to extract the first and last number in a string

Tags: regex

Using these expressions separately, I can extract weight and price from this string, how can I get this to work in a single combined expression?

String:

```
  0.280    Price $   2.49
```

Expressions

```
(?<weight>\.?\d+(\x2E\d+))
(?<price>\d+\.\d+$)
```

Comment: Combine them with `.*`.

Comment: `(\d+\.\d+).*(\d+\.\d+)$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<weight>\.?\d+(?:\x2E\d+)).*?(?<price>\d+\.\d+$)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/zR2tR4/21

Comment: even though I don't get why not simply `(?<weight>\d+\.\d+).*?(?<price>\d+\.\d+$)`

Comment: @NicolaMiotto i actually just used OP's regex's.Didnt check much :P